# Help adding multiple blogs / content areas on a page

Tags: nodes, blocks, theming

Hi how do I set 4 editable content/blogs block/nodes on a page... i'm trying to do this format https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFoCY.jpg

main Box 1: width 556 x length 630

right Box 1 : width 210 x length 275

right Box 2 : width 210 x length 185

right Box 3 : width 210 x length 150

also how can I edit the style/css for the blocks/nodes on this page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define new block regions in your theme, and structure your page.tpl.php to print the regions in the desired structure.  You should look through the [theming tutorials](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme)

If that is the layout for a single page only, you might want to look into [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels), though be warned that there is a bit of a learning curve.

For styles of blocks, you can override the default CSS in your theme.  Your theme's CSS files will load after the defaults, so it will take precedence.

Comment: yes its for a single page, layout. Is there a good video tutorial on Panels. i'm still unsure as to how to set the panels

Comment: The written ones are pretty good, and there are some videos here: http://drupal.org/node/496278